# Kotlin WebAssembly access DOM

Tags: dom, kotlin, webassembly

I've got the following code in Kotlin

```
import kotlinx.interop.wasm.dom.*
import kotlinx.wasm.jsinterop.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val veryImportantCalculation = 42

    //access the #wasm in html and append it to the element

}
```

which is compiled to wasmFunctions.wasm,

and an extremely easy HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script wasm="./wasmFunctions.wasm" src="./wasmFunctions.wasm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <label id='wasm'></label>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to put the veryImportantCalculation value from Kotlin-to-wasm code in the #wasm label. Is there a way to with the imported dom library?